# MySQL get lowest 3 values by user

Tags: mysql, sorting, group-by

I have a MySQL database and I want to SUM the lowest 3 Point by a Person.

```
+--------+--------+
| Person | Points |
+--------+--------+
| 1      | 15     |
| 1      | 10     |
| 1      | 5      |
| 1      | 10     |
| 2      | 5      |
| 2      | 4      |
| 2      | 3      |
| 2      | 2      |
| 3      | 1      |
| 3      | 1      |
| 3      | 1      |
+--------+--------+
```

The result what I want:

```
+-------+-----+
| 1     | 25  |
| 2     | 9   |
| 3     | 3   |
+-------+-----+
```

But I am really lost how to solve this. This is my Query Until now, :

```
SELECT person, SUM(points) FROM (SELECT SUM(points) FROM table 
GROUP BY person ORDER BY points ASC LIMIT 3)
```

This is my SQL Create Script:

```
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `person` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `points` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ;

INSERT INTO `mytable` (`person`, `points`) VALUES
(1, 15),
(1, 10),
(1, 5),
(1, 10),
(2, 5),
(2, 4),
(2, 3),
(2, 2),
(3, 1),
(3, 1),
(3, 1);
```

Comment: See [_Groupwise Max_](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a row number in the inner query as a helper to limit the rows.Row number and not limit to avoid the duplicate values problem.Not tested but it should work,too lazy to create a fiddle.

```
SELECT Person,SUM(Points) FROM
(SELECT Person,Points,
CASE Person
         WHEN @person THEN @rank:= @rank+ 1 
         ELSE @rank:= 1
     END AS rank,
     @person:= person 
FROM t, (SELECT @rank:= 0,@person:='') x
ORDER BY Points ASC)y
WHERE y.rank<=3
GROUP BY Persons
```

[FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/157cc/3)

Comment: I tried it, but the error I got is: Unknown collumn 'type' in field list.

This is the SQL script to create the table:
Maybe you can help me with http://sqlfiddle.com ??

I added my Create Script.